# Flutter - How to make lazy loading on PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to lazily load widget in a `PageView`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `PageView.builder` for this.

Example:

```
PageView.builder(
  itemCount: 100,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => YourWidget(),
),
```